# Erro ao validar login

Tags: java, login, interface

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
package br.edu.utfpr.exer07;

    /*
    7) Implementar uma interface que contenha os métodos à ser usados:
    a. double soma(double valor1, double valor2, double valor3);
    b. String calculaTabuada(double tabuada, double valorInicial, double
    valorFinal);
    c. boolean login(String login, String senha);
    Implementar uma classe utilizando encapsulamento para armazenar cada tipo
    dos valores de retornos desta interface e que esta classe implemente esta
    interface e que contenha mais os métodos para apresentar cada um dos
    valores.
     */

public interface Calculos {

    public double soma(double valor1, double valor2, double valor3);
    public String calculaTabuada(double tabuada, double valorInicial, double valorFinal);
    public boolean login(String login, String senha);       
}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer07;

/*
7) Implementar uma interface que contenha os métodos à ser usados:
a. double soma(double valor1, double valor2, double valor3);
b. String calculaTabuada(double tabuada, double valorInicial, double
valorFinal);
c. boolean login(String login, String senha);
Implementar uma classe utilizando encapsulamento para armazenar cada tipo
dos valores de retornos desta interface e que esta classe implemente esta
interface e que contenha mais os métodos para apresentar cada um dos
valores.
 */

public class ExecutaCalculos implements Calculos {

    private double valor1;
    private double valor2;
    private double valor3;
    private double tabuada;
    private double valorInicial;
    private double valorFinal;
    private String login = "adm";
    private String senha = "123";

    public double getValor1() {
        return valor1;
    }

    public void setValor1(double valor1) {
        this.valor1 = valor1;
    }

    public double getValor2() {
        return valor2;
    }

    public void setValor2(double valor2) {
        this.valor2 = valor2;
    }

    public double getValor3() {
        return valor3;
    }

    public void setValor3(double valor3) {
        this.valor3 = valor3;
    }

    public double getTabuada() {
        return tabuada;
    }

    public void setTabuada(double tabuada) {
        this.tabuada = tabuada;
    }

    public double getValorInicial() {
        return valorInicial;
    }

    public void setValorInicial(double valorInicial) {
        this.valorInicial = valorInicial;
    }

    public double getValorFinal() {
        return valorFinal;
    }

    public void setValorFinal(double valorFinal) {
        this.valorFinal = valorFinal;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    @Override
    public double soma(double valor1, double valor2, double valor3) {
        return valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    }

    @Override
    public String calculaTabuada(double tabuada, double valorInicial, double valorFinal) {
        for(double i=  valorInicial; i<=valorFinal; i++) {
            System.out.println(tabuada+" X "+i+" = "+tabuada*i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login(String login, String senha) {
        boolean estado;
        if(login == this.login && senha == this.senha) {
            System.out.println("Login efeituado com sucesso");
            estado = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login e/ou senha inválidos");
            estado = false;
        }
        return estado;
    }
}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer07;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exer07 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ExecutaCalculos ec = new ExecutaCalculos();

        //ec.setLogin(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login: "));
        //ec.setSenha(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Senha: "));

        if(ec.login((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login: ")), (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Senha: "))) == true) {
            System.out.println("| 1 - Somar            |"
                             + "| 2 - Calcular tabuada |");
            int opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(("1 - Soma\n"
                                                                    + "2 - Calcular tabuada\n"
                                                                    + "Opção: ")));
            switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                ec.setValor1(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o primeiro valor:")));
                ec.setValor2(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o segundo valor:")));
                ec.setValor3(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o terceiro valor:")));
                System.out.println(ec.soma(ec.getValor1(), ec.getValor2(), ec.getValor2()));
                break;
            case 2:
                ec.setTabuada(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a tabuada que deseja calcular:")));
                ec.setValorInicial(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o valor inicial:")));
                ec.setValorFinal(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o valor final")));
                ec.calculaTabuada(ec.getTabuada(), ec.getValorInicial(), ec.getValorFinal());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

E ao executar esse `if` na classe `main`, chamando o método `login` da classe `ExecutarCalculos`, ele sempre retorna `false`. Qual pode ser o problema?

```
if(ec.login((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login: ")), (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Senha: "))) == true)
```

Comment: Para objetos (ou seja, tipos não primitivos) o `==` verifica se os dois apontam para o mesmo espaço de memória. Então, como está comparando *strings* , utilize `equals`.

Comment: Ótimo, como não pensei nisso antes? hahahaha Muito obrigado

Comment: OK, inclui uma resposta só para deixar registrado mesmo =D

Comment: Não reparei que era a mesma pessoa hehehehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um erro comum este que você tem, acredito que todos já tenham passado por isto =)

Em java quando `==` é usado para comparar dois objetos ele verifica se ambos objetos apontam para o mesmo espaço de memória. Um exemplo com `String` seria este:

```
final String string1 = new String("String");
final String string2 = "String";
final String string3 = string1;
final String string4 = "String";
if (string1 == string2) {
    System.out.println("string1 e string2 são o mesmo objeto.");
} else {
    System.out.println("string1 e string2 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.");
}
if (string1.equals(string2)) {
    System.out.println("string1 e string2 possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.");
} else {
    System.out.println("string1 e string2 NÃO possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.");
}
if (string1 == string3) {
    System.out.println("string1 e string3 são o mesmo objeto.");
} else {
    System.out.println("string1 e string3 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.");
}
if (string1 == string4) {
    System.out.println("string1 e string4 são o mesmo objeto.");
} else {
    System.out.println("string1 e string4 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.");
}
if (string2 == string4) {
    System.out.println("string2 e string4 são o mesmo objeto.");
} else {
    // dead code, sempre será igual
    System.out.println("string2 e string4 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.");
}
if (string3.equals(string4)) {
    System.out.println("string3 e string4 possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.");
} else {
    System.out.println("string3 e string4 NÃO possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.");
}
```

Que resultaria nisto:

```
string1 e string2 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.
string1 e string2 possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.
string1 e string3 são o mesmo objeto.
string1 e string4 NÃO são o mesmo objeto.
string2 e string4 são o mesmo objeto.
string3 e string4 possuem o mesmo conteúdo, mas não o mesmo.
```

Ou seja, sabemos que sempre o conteúdo da `String` é o mesmo, ou seja, **String**. No entanto temos neste caso dois objetos diferentes, em outras palavras, ocupamos dois espaços de memória diferentes com o mesmo conteúdo. Qualquer combinação com o `equals` será sempre igual, mas com o `==` não, já que entre `string1` e `string2` ou `string4` será falso.

Nestes casos normalmente é usado o método [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) de [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) que verifica a equidade de conteúdo, quando sobrescrito. Por padrão apenas verifica se apontam para o mesmo espaço de memória.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!